# Plaid API does not return pending transactions

Tags: plaid

I am using the public API endpoint

```
/connect/get
options={"pending":true}
```

to get the pending transactions for the user, once he is added.

However, I am not getting any pending transactions in the results.

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: What response are you getting and what is the full block of code you are using to submit?

Comment: Additionally, are you using the sandbox or live API?

Comment: I am using the live API

Comment: I am having similar issue.  On tartan,  with live account connection,  i am not getting recent pending or posted transactions.

Comment: did you guys ever figure this issue? im having the same problem